# Removing columns with sklearn's OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder as LE, OneHotEncoder as OHE
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,100],[1,2,200],[2,3,400]])


oh = OHE(categorical_features=[0,1])
a = oh.fit_transform(a).toarray()
```

Let's assume first and second column are categorical data. This code does one hot encoding, but for the regression problem, I would like to remove first column after encoding categorical data. In this example, there are two and I could do it manually. But what if you have many categorical features, how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy`'s fancy indexing and slice off the first column:

```
>>> a
array([[   1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,    0.,    0.,  100.],
       [   0.,    1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,    0.,  200.],
       [   0.,    0.,    1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,  400.]])
>>> a[:, 1:]
array([[   0.,    0.,    1.,    0.,    0.,  100.],
       [   1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,    0.,  200.],
       [   0.,    1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,  400.]])
```

---

If you have an list of columns you want to delete, here's how you'd do that:

```
>>> idx_to_delete = [0, 3]
>>> indices = [i for i in range(a.shape[-1]) if i not in idx_to_delete]
>>> indices
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[:, indices]
array([[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  100.],
       [   1.,    0.,    1.,    0.,  200.],
       [   0.,    1.,    0.,    1.,  400.]])
```

Comment: Yes, this would eliminate first column of first categorical set. But what if I have 1000 categories and I need to delete for each first column after one hot encoding?

Comment: The concept remains the same, you may extend it to the 3rd dimension like this: `a[:, :, 1:]`

Comment: Excuse me once again, however I receive this error: builtins.IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: I'm assuming `a` is a 3d array?

Comment: a = a[:,1:], would "delete" first column... OK, but what if I need to delete 1st and 4th column?

Comment: Are the features you want to delete likely to be random? Or do you want to delete every 2 columns... or what? How is your use case looking like? That would give me a better idea.

Comment: @Makaroniiii Look at my edit for a generic solution for your problem.

Comment: To avoid Multicollinearity you must delete one column per categorical column. In my example dataset there are two categorical features. For each I want to delete first column after one hot encoding first. a[:,1:] deletes only first column of first categorical features.

Comment: Got it... You'll have to do something like: `x = np.array([oh.fit_transform(a).toarray() for a in categorical_features]); x_new = x[:, :, 1:]`

Answer (score 5):

For that I use a Wrapper like that which is also usable in Pipelines:

```
class DummyEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_values='auto'):
        self.n_values = n_values

    def transform(self, X):
        ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, n_values=self.n_values)
        return ohe.fit_transform(X)[:,:-1]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely with pipelines. Although I used `return ohe.fit_transform(X)[:,1:]` to remove 1st column rather than the last.

Answer (score 1):

To do this automatically, we get a list of indices to drop before applying one hot encoding by identifying the most common levels in the categorical features. This is because the most common level serves best as the base level, allowing the importance of other levels to be evaluated.

After applying one hot encoding, we get the list of indices to keep and use it drop the previously determined columns.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder as OHE
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([[0,1,100],[1,2,200],[2,3,400]])

def get_indices_to_drop(X_before_OH, categorical_indices_list):
    # Returns list of index to drop after doing one hot encoding
    # Dropping most common level within the categorical variable
    # This is because the most common level serves best as the base level,
    # Allowing the importance of other levels to be evaluated
    indices_to_drop = []
    indices_accum = 0
    for i in categorical_indices_list:
        most_common = pd.Series(X_before_OH[:,i]).value_counts().index[0]
        indices_to_drop.append(most_common + indices_accum)
        indices_accum += len(np.unique(X_before_OH[:,i])) - 1
    return indices_to_drop

indices_to_drop = get_indices_to_drop(a, [0, 1])

oh = OHE(categorical_features=[0,1])
a = oh.fit_transform(a).toarray()

def get_indices_to_keep(X_after_OH, index_to_drop_list):
    return [i for i in range(X_after_OH.shape[-1]) if i not in index_to_drop_list]

indices_to_keep = get_indices_to_keep(a, indices_to_drop)
a = a[:, indices_to_keep]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the limitation of the One-Hot encoder in Sklearn when dealing with building models. The best way to do that if you have multiple categorical variables is first to use LabelEncoder to identify the unique labels for each categorical variables and then utilize them to generate the indexes to delete. As an example, if you have the data in a numpy array as X, with categorical variables in FIRST_IDX, SECOND_IDX, THIRD_IDX columns, first encode them using LabelEncoder.

```
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, FIRST_IDX] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, FIRST_IDX])

labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, SECOND_IDX] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, SECOND_IDX])

labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, THIRD_IDX] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, THIRD_IDX])
```

Then apply One-Hot Encoder, which will create the representation at the beginning of the array for all categorical variables, one after the other.

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[FIRST_IDX, SECOND_IDX, THIRD_IDX])

X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Finally, eliminate the first entry for each categorical variable by leveraging the size of unique values for each categorical variables and using the cumulative sum (here the cumulative sum gives you the first entry index of the categorical variables) in numpy.

```
index_to_delete = np.cumsum([0,
               len(labelencoder_X_1.classes_),
               len(labelencoder_X_2.classes_),
               len(labelencoder_X_3.classes_)
               ])
index_to_keep = [i for i in range(X.shape[1]) if i not in index_to_delete]

X = X[:, index_to_keep]
```

Now X contains the data ready to be used in any modeling task.